# Pattern grouping doesent work in HTML5

Tags: regex, html

I try to match this RegExp `pattern="([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*){4,}"` which means:

Always start with alphabetic, then if he wants to add a number, all this must be minimum 4; `aaaa` is validated, but `aaa4` is not.

The trick I did is `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}` so I can oblige the first character to be a letter, then there is `at least 4 alphanumeric`.

Comment: Why mention HTML5 like it's relevant? Why do you think it matters?

Comment: the number can only be at the end ? Or after the first letter then followed by other letters ?

Comment: for example `a123` or `aaaa` but never `1aaa`

Comment: @Rudie: It matters, since HTML5 hints that it's the pattern attribute of input tag, which uses JavaScript's RegExp and anchors the pattern.

Comment: @nhahtdh I completely missed the `pattern="` part. Mi scusi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that always start with alphabetic and finish with one or more optional number (must be the minimum 4 elements) your regexp should be

```
pattern="([a-zA-Z]{4,}\d*|[a-zA-Z]{3,}\d+)"
```

Although you could want this solution

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}
```

In this case you get one alphabet and after three or more alphabetic and numbers characters.

Comment: I did this `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}` so there is always minimum one alphabet and the rest will be whatever in alphanumeric, so the total will be at least 5.

Comment: That's true. I understand you that you want start with alphabet and finish with one or more optional numbers. In your case if you only want 4 characteres change the number {4,} to {3,}

Comment: sadly I thought using the `()` will capture what is between parentheses and will then use this expression with the `{n,}`

Comment: The operator {} is applied to expression which preceded. So, in your case will be applied to [a-zA-Z0-9]. I just update my answer.

Comment: the `+` isn't usefull here.

Comment: @naurel that's true. Isn't necessary.

Comment: yes, I think this will be faster to execute, since there is always one alphabet, but why `([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*){4,}"` doesent work? why only the first part which is taken and the numbers are ignored, as i understand, that means apply `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*` with a minimum 4 char, no?

Comment: Because the operator{4,} forces to repeat at least 4 times the pattern ([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*). In this pattern the operator + forces at least one time to appear [a-zA-Z] while that the operator * doesn't force to appear (it includes the zero repetion). I recommend that you play with this page https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

What your current pattern actually does is look for one or more letters followed by 0 or more numbers, and that entire pattern has to repeat a minimum of 4 times.

To get what you want you would need to use a pipe and specify the two different patterns and a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{4,}|[a-zA-Z]+(?![0-9])
```

Which means look for `a-z` one or more times followed by 4 or more digits *or* look for `a-z` one or more  times and not followed by a digit.

```html
Enter text: <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{4,}|[a-zA-Z]+(?![0-9])">
```

Comment: sorry, i was refering to html5 `pattern` attribute :D

Comment: @Abdelouahab Ah. Forgot they added that.